# Sharepoint wysiwyg editor not working in IE

Tags: 2010, internet-explorer

When opening our sharepoint (2010) site and trying to edit an element in Internet Explorer, it just shows the editor toolbar blank. The field itself contains text - as you can see from the second screenshot.

[image: Blank editor]

In Chrome, I can see the content but it's no editor and it prints all the HTML code.

[image: HTML In Chrome]

What could be the cause of this?
Could the built-in editor be failing? Are there any way of repairing this?
I have tried switching compability mode on and off in my IE 10, but still get the same result.

Edit:

OK! More information! I just popped open the dev-tools and console in my IE 10 when launching the edit window shown above. It throws the first error on open, and if I try to hover the buttons in the editor, it throws the second one. Is the entire thing broken? Are there any way of fixing a hostile javascript?

[image: Errors in console]

> Error 1 : SCRIPT5002: Expected a function
>
> Error 2: SCRIPT5007: Can't get the property hoverButton when it's undefined or has a nullreference.

(Pardon the rough translation..)

As I just got this case handed over I don't know much about changes that has been done I'm afraid.. I just got to fix it!

Edit 2: Added more information about js included.

[image: Javascripts]

Comment: Can you look in the browser javascript console for any errors thrown?

Comment: Could very well be a browser compatibility issue. Have you encountered this issue on previous solutions beforehand?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Just gave the post an update!

Comment: @DanielZiga I have tried in IE8, IE9 and IE10. Still no go. Other browsers are not supported by sharepoint and you get the HTML style ^ that I got in Chrome (so that's fine!)

Comment: Do you have any custom javascript on the page? Either in the pagelayout or the masterpage that could conflict with SharePoints own javascripts?

Comment: @DanielZiga from what I can tell, there is nothing suspicious. How would I continue to make sure? I'm not quite sure what access my user needs and where I need to go to find out..

Comment: One way to check is in IE's developer tool. Under the Script tab there is a dropdown which iterates all of the JS files being loaded. Here check for anything that is not loaded directly from `_layouts/1033`.

Comment: @DanielZiga couldn't find any dropdown listing the scripts in IE 10.. From what I could see: <script src="/Style Library/v5/script/v5.js"></script> is one of the .js's beeing loaded in HEAD that's not in the 1044 folder. And there are two instances of ScriptResource.axd with a pretty long tail..

Comment: @DanielZiga OK, I think I found something. Post is updated!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8878/discussion-between-daniel-ziga-and-xstnc)

Comment: In the console error message, click on the link to the form.js file. Your error will likely be in that file. (Is there a chance this was built in 2007 and migrated?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common scenario where you face `n` number of issues with newer version of browsers.

Temporary solution is to tweak in your `web.config` like:

```
add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7"
```

Reference: [my website does not work well with newly released version of IE](http://sharepoint.asia/my-website-does-not-work-well-with-newly-released-version-of-ie/)

[Note: it's my own blog]